# Nested div - position absolute - z-index

Tags: css, html, nested, z-index

I have a little problem with a nested div to be overlayed by its parent div, searched here already but no solution will fit for my problem.

Sample CSS:

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    min-height: 530px;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#category {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="category"></div>
</div>
```

What it should look like:

The nested div `#category` should stick to the top right of the `#content` and should be behind it, so that the `#content` will overlay it.
I know that it's maybe not the best way to handle it but I need to do it that way, due to the crappy style of the whole project (I'm just adjusting it a bit).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `#category { pointer-events: visible; }` although I don't think that's supported in IE so this may help you: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Answer (score 5):

In order to put child element behind it's parent, you have to use negative values for `z-index`:

```css
#category {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtWDN/1/)**

Comment: In combination with position: relative? So it's not possible with position: absolute?

Comment: Ok sorry I think I need to be a bit more precise, as the sample is not what I have here exactly.
I have a containt around it too:

`code`#container {
 width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: @BenG You must set `position` in order to make `z-index` working. It doesn't matter if it's `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, got it working after all...the whole design is really crappy, seems like the issue was somewhere else, got it working after cleaning up the whole CSS!